# Getting Webpage Title, Img, Metadata info from Linux Terminal

Tags: bash, html, sh

is there any way or any tools that I could use to get from a SH script, a webpage title, metadata such as descriptions, maybe a little screenshot of the webpage or anything like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use curl or wget to get the webpage, and then pipe it to sed to get the contents of various tags. It's kludgy *as*, but that's kinda what you're going to get if you're doing this stuff with a shell script.

eg

```
wget http://example.com -O - | grep \<title\>|sed "s/\<title\>\([^<]*\).*/\1/"
```

will give you the contents of the title tag. Note that in this example it gives you the raw un-parsed source, so it looks like `IANA &mdash; Example domains` instead of `IANA – Example domains`.

Have you considered using something like perl?