# How to get title of website in linux terminal

Tags: linux

I have this code 
**wget [google.com](http://www.google.com/)**

the above command is giving me the detail of the website like URL,IP address,ect.
i not able to get the title of the website in Linux terminal?

Help?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711339/getting-webpage-title-img-metadata-info-from-linux-terminal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
$ curl -L example.com | grep '<title>'
```

The `-L` switch causes `curl` to follow redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Learn more about [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) and [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) (perhaps on http://www.w3schools.com/ which is rumored to have many mistakes).

You may want to get the content inside `<title>` tag of `<head>` element of `<html>`

BTW, some web pages might not have statically any such `<title>` tag, if they are using [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript) and [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) techniques to dynamically change the page in the browser to have a title.

Comment: I don't know, I did the `curl` I mentioned in my answer and I got a `<title>` somewhere.